# Query different tabs from 1 sheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I'm trying to add 2 queries in one from 2 different tabs, but it's not working, i have spent so many hours to try to fix this issue....
And sometimes, one of the query doesn't have result in one or the other tab.

```
=if(isblank(B11),,IFNA(query({Dividendes_TFSA!$B$9:$H$56,Dividendes_RRSP!$B$9:$H$56},"select Col7 where Col2='"&B11&"' and Col3 like '%Mars%'"),""))
```

[image: image1]

If I do only one tab, it's working perfectly.

```
=if(isblank(B10),,IFNA(query(Dividendes_RRSP!$B$9:$H$56,"select G where B='"&B10&"' and C like '%Mars%'"),""))
```

[image: image2]

Here the "Dividendes_RRSP" tab (the Dividendes_TFSA it's the same with different stocks)

[image: image3]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B11),,IFNA(QUERY(
 {Dividendes_TFSA!$B$9:$H$56; Dividendes_RRSP!$B$9:$H$56},
 "select Col7 
  where Col2='"&B11&"'
    and Col3 like '%Mars%'")))
```

---

### update:

```
=IF(ISBLANK($B7),,IFNA(QUERY({Dividendes_TFSA!A:F;Dividendes_RRSP!A6:F},
 "select sum(Col6) 
  where Col2='"&$B7&"' 
    and Col3 like '%Mars%' 
  label sum(Col6)''")))
```

[image]

Comment: It's not working. But thank you for the try.

Comment: @breizangelik can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Here the link, it's in French, but i'm sure it's still understandable ;)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R-8Z8M9ruIclxI8JUO9FQBJXwIl1Aq8snPlzNXoyZw0/edit?usp=sharing
It's a very simple table as it's normally a paid table. 
Thank you in advance for your help and time.